# Why isn't Buildout downloading my dependencies?

Tags: python, setuptools, buildout

Buildout seems to have always just worked™ in the past, but I can't seem to get it to download my dependencies this go-around. Here's my `buildout.cfg`:

```
[buildout]
parts = python_section
develop = .
eggs = buildoutstarter
versions = versions

[versions] 

[python_section]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

Here's my `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "buildoutstarter",
    version = "0.1.0",
    license = "LGPL",
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = { '': 'src'},
    install_requires = ['setuptools',
        'jinja2',
    ],
)
```

Unfortunately, running `bin/buildout` doesn't seem to download Jinja at all. In fact, running `find . -iname "*jinja*"` doesn't yield anything, so it's apparent that Buildout isn't doing anything with the package. Why isn't it downloading the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildout will use packages already installed in your python `site-packages` unless you tell it not to:

```
include-site-packages = false
```

`include-site-packages` is set to `true` by default.

You can also whitelist what packages are allowed to be satisfied from your site-packages:

```
include-site-packages = true
allowed-eggs-from-site-packages = jinja2,mako
```

Which would *only* allow the `jinja2` and `mako` packages to be taken from your site-packages but nothing else.

`allowed-eggs-from-site-packages` supports globs and is set to `*` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Buildout is actually a bit 'smarter' than I had originally thought. Since the dependency 'jinja2 == 2.6' was already satisfied on my machine, it simply created a link to that package, which is why it didn't download it. Interesting.